# Why would Sarah need to convince Hagar?

Tags: marriage, parashat-lech-lecha, slave-serve-eved-avadim, sarah, hagar

Asking for someone else. Rashi on the parsha, Beresheet 16:3, brings a midrash from Beresheet Rabbah 45:3 [which says](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Rashi_on_Genesis.16.3.1?lang=bi&p2=Bereishit_Rabbah.45.3&lang2=bi):

> "And Sarai, the wife of Abram, took Hagar the Egyptian, her maidservant (Genesis 16:3) - took her with words, saying "you are fortunate to be clinging to such a holy body like his!""

Previously she had been a maidservant with little chance of this status changing - why wouldn't she jump at the chance to become one of the mistresses of the household? Why would Sarah need to convince her to do it?

Comment: Trying to find it inside but I saw that the Anaf Yosef says that Sarah persuaded her because Hagar was concerned that Avram couldn't have children

Comment: I don't think Hagar would become a mistress of the household at all. Her status remained the same, which is why Sarah was able to retaliate against her.